Blender is being difficult in edit mode
I have my object set to a very specific size for a very specific reason.  I'm trying to cut a square out of it, so I'm going into edit mode and adding a plane.  I cannot change the scale of the plane by actual values in edit mode, and if I exit edit mode, it treats it as a part of the same object and so I still can't change the scale of it.  This means that I cannot make it a specific size at all.  This project flatout will not work if this doesn't.

Hello maybe show some screenshots?

That's because it is part of the same object if you add it in Edit mode! Add it in Object mode and you can scale it as you wish.

It's very easy to make simple geometry be specific size in Blender in Edit mode as well. You can just move things with numerical input.
So say I want a plane that is 12cm x 2.5in(Yep, different units, that's just how it was measured for some reason :D ). I could:

Duplicate some single vertex in my model( Shift  +  D ) and move it where I want the first corner of my plane to be.
Hit  E  to extrude and before finishing that operation hit  X  too constrain movent in X axis, then(still before finishing that operation) hit  Numpad *  to enter advanced numerical input mode then just type "12cm" and hit enter to finish the operation.
Hit  Ctrl  +  +  to grow the selection or  Ctrl  +  L  to select all linked geometry.
And finally extrude the now selected edge exactly the same way but in Y axis and type "2.5in" instead of "12cm" this time.

The units will get converted to meters that I have selected in my Units settings in Scene tab of Properties editor.
If you know the measurements in the units you actually work in you can skip the  Numpad *  for advanced numerical input mode and just enter them without units at the end.


It seems like an XY problem, because how will you cut a hole with a plane in Edit mode(or anywhere really)? But it seems like a useful bit of information that you can definitely work with precision in Edit mode... And what do I know, maybe you can model other geometry around it and delete it?.. or maybe use it for snapping?..

This works, thanks

Yep, I thought of an XY problem as well... because cutting a hole would be done better with adding cutter objects in Object Mode - but it seems the OP is not even really aware of the differences of doing things in either Edit Mode or Object Mode. And on the other hand, a strange way of doing it in Edit Mode could be to create a plane somewhere where you want the hole to be, delete surrounding faces, connect the remains to the plane, then delete the plane. Surely not the best idea, but doable  :D

No, I'm not particularly aware of the ins and outs of Blender.  I was okay at using it at one point several months ago, and then I didn't use it for several months and forgot almost everything.  Even when I briefly used it, I found the knife tool frustrating and did what I would've done with it by hand.  However, to get a specific measurement like I need, there doesn't seem to be much of a better option.

@LunaLunarNelson Not sure I get what you are trying to say here. It's only one example how you can work precisely, there are usually plenty of options though. If you want further advice on options, you should provide more detail and context about your actual problem which we know nothing about at this point. If you share screenshots and tell us what the precise problem is, it's possible you might get more specific answers and it's possible you might find out about other options.
